# AWS Cloudformation : Encountered unsupported property LaunchConfigurationName

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How do we create Launch configurations in cloudformation with specific name.? I looked at the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html, there is no property that sets the name of the launch configuration that we create in template. 
Is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to name the `LaunchConfiguration` yourself, as cloudformation need to setup its own name to be able to update it later.

Usually, the `LauchConfiguration` will be named according to the stack and resource name from the template, something like: `{stack-name}-{resource-name}-{AWS-generated-id}`, this gived me for example: `amp-g2g-preprod-api-ec2-ApiLaunchConfiguration-1PQ85HXBX7DVC`.

If you need to reference anywhere else your `LaunchConfiguration`, use [{"Ref":"..."}](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) from within the template, or use [output export/import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) from another template.

Comment: Guess thats it then. Thanks for confirming. I don't understand why such a simple thing is not there. we can set autoscaling group name but not launch configuration, is there any particular reason?. I can have custom resource to update/create my launch configuration as i needed. Too bad we cannot set the naming convention inside template.

Comment: I think you can name auto scaling group so you can create new one on update, without touching an already existing one, not sure I'm clear or right here... Anyway, don't name it or you will not be able to update it using the cloudformatiom stack